# SVN for DO178-B objectives

Tags: svn, do178-b

I am doing a feasibility study to see if SVN can be used for maintaining a DO-178B/C project. Most of the DO178 projects I have seen uses CVS or similar configuration management tool which maintain versions for each file separately (which is not same as SVN). Here are some of the derived objectives for configuration management which are required by my project:

1. For each file, complete modification history shall be available.
2. There should be a way to prove that each version of file has been proofread. This demands that there should be a way to list all the modifications done on particular file since some previous TAG.
3. For each modification done, a grouping should be possible by which I can figure out which files were modified for a common requirement. Normally we use a hashtag for each modification done in modification history comments. If same hashtag occurs in multiple files, they belong to same group.
4. Finally a configuration index report should be available which lists the summary for each file modification independently since some already existing TAG. Normally this summary involves the baseline version of file, and then for each modification done since, list of hashtags for each modification and then the final version.

Does anyone know how can I use SVN so that i am still able to provide these reports to the software auditors.

Comment: It's all possible with Subversion. Have you read the documentation? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/

Comment: I am just curious regarding point 2. SVN provides a mechanism to list all modifications done on a particular file - fine. But does SVN really have a built-in mechanism to proove, that a file/change has been proofread (e.g. forced reviews, or whatever?)

Answer (score 1):

Any CM tool can be used as long as all the SCM Process Objectives in Table 7-1 are satisfied. I think SVN can be used but cannot achieve all objectives. We also need other tool like Jira to do change control and problem reporting.

[image]